# Computing Singular Value Decomposition of small ($4\times 4$) matrices

Tags: algorithms, c++, matrix-factorization, svd

I need to compute the Singular Value Decomposition (SVD) of many $4 \times 4$ matrices. I'm looking for SVD algorithms specialized for small matrices. I've read that the `std::vector` sorting algorithm in the C++ STL is often hardcoded for short vectors for optimal performance. I want to hard code the SVD for the case $4 \times 4$ matrices.

What information is there about optimally solving small cases of SVD?

Comment: Related, but 2x2: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/8899/robust-algorithm-for-2-times-2-svd,  https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/10972/singular-value-decomposition-of-a-2-x-2-complex-matrix

Comment: That said, I would be skeptical of anything that does not rely on orthogonal transformations, even if it claims to be 'closed-form'.

Comment: The Eigen library provides templates to perform SVD on fixed-size matrices. This will save some memory, and may provide some performance advantage with vectorized operations. I think `Eigen::JacobiSVD<Matrix<float, 4, 4>, Eigen::NoQRPreconditioner>` would be optimal for your problem, as no preconditioner is required for square matrices.

https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1JacobiSVD.html